# Prevent Chrome from Swallowing NFC Deep-Links

Tags: android, nfc, deep-linking

I have an Android test app set up to be opened from a Deep Link from NFC records.  It works, but ONLY if Chrome is disabled.  If Chrome is not disabled, it will not even ask, it will ONLY open Chrome.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As you can see, it is registered both for VIEW and NDEF_DISCOVERED actions.  On VIEW actions (such as clicking on a link from Slack), it will ask if I want to open Chrome or my app.  However, for NDEF_DISCOVERED actions, if Chrome is not disabled, it will just open Chrome directly.  If Chrome is disabled, it will them ask about opening my app.

I have heard that this may be related to Android 10, but I didn't know if there was a permission I could request or something that would bypass this behavior.  I am trying it out on a OnePlus 6T running Android 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android NFC tag with URL opening browser, not my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678720/android-nfc-tag-with-url-opening-browser-not-my-app)

Comment: @Jameido - that's an equivalent problem, but doesn't answer the question.  The answer presumes a bunch of stuff that I haven't done.  I've tried it on multiple phones to the same effect.  Chrome is not set to swallow all URLs, and in fact does not do so when it comes from a non-NFC source.  It is only on NFC sources that Chrome seems to auto-swallow URLs no matter what the intent declaration.